# Entity Framework get entity via variable

Tags: entity-framework-4.3

I have a listbox populated with table names.  I want to be able to click a row in the listbox and return all records from that table and bind to a datagridview.  Using good old fashioned SQL this is a piece of cake. Attempting to do the same with Entity Framework 4.3.1 is another matter.

For instance, is there a way to represent "get_picklist_names_v" as a variable in this code below?

```
static class EfHelper
{
    public static EfEntities CreateContext()
    {
        EfEntities context = new EfEntities();
        return context;
    }
}

using (var context = EfHelper.CreateContext())
{
    IList list = context.get_picklist_names_v.ToList();

    lboPicklist.DataSource = list;
    lboPicklist.DisplayMember = "name";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Entity Framework abstact the SQL stuff with types and does its best so you don't have to write sql for each server flavor (Oracle, SQL Server, MySQL, etc.).  That's what an ORM does...

If your used to generic types its quite trivial to do the same with Entity Framework.

It's not exactly what yor looking for but maybe you can find some hints from the followig article   :

[Repository Pattern with Entity Framework](http://dotnetspeak.com/index.php/2011/03/repository-pattern-with-entity-framework/)

Answer (score 0):

Entity Framework is not the best tool to achieve this. You could try [Entity Sql](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb387145.aspx), but the problem is that in order to use that in a dynamic way you have to capture the results in an `IEnumerable<DbDataRecord>`. A `DataGridView` won't display that as such.

There is nothing more convenient for this than filling a DataSet by a TableAdapter and a sql statement. I would stick to that if I were you.